# I want resoult of search opens in new tab

Tags: php

hi i use this code to find a file on directory specified. this works but i want that when i click on resoutt it opens in new tab

code is:

```
<?php
$dir = 'ups';
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess');
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtolower($_GET['q']) : '';
$res = opendir($dir);
while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) {
if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) {
echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file</a>";
echo "<br>";
}
}
closedir($res);
?>
```

when i use

```
<?php
echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file target = "_blank"</a>";
?>
```

this shows:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in    /home/u688698883/public_html/search/ss.php on line 8
```

Comment: If you just want your `$file` openned in the new tab, add `target="_blank"` to your `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href = "something.php" target = "_blank">
```

This opens a new tab / window depending on user preference. Please search before posting.

[Open link in new tab or window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551779/open-link-in-new-tab)

In your case:

```
<?php
  echo "<a href='$dir/$file' target = '_blank'>$file</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Common PHP knowledge says you need to escape the key or use single quotations.    <a href = \"something.php\" target = \"_blank\">

Comment: it shows this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/u688698883/public_html/search/ss.php on line 8"