# How do you make a caption link target a new window in lightbox?

Tags: html, css

I tried adding the target="new" in the link, but it's not working.

```
<a href="images/fiandre/fiandre3.jpg" data-lightbox="fiandre" data-title="<a href='http://www.granitifiandre.com/porcelain-tile/technical-ceramic/granite-tiles/' target="new">New Granite</a>"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open link in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551779/open-link-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 0):

Use `target="_blank"` to do this.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551842/2654498), and [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) for more information on `Target`

Comment: Here is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707960/lightbox-2-removes-target-blanks-behavior-in-data-title/27036754#27036754

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add target="_blank"

```
<a href="images/fiandre/fiandre3.jpg" data-lightbox="fiandre" data-title="<a href='http://www.granitifiandre.com/porcelain-tile/technical-ceramic/granite-tiles/' target="_blank">New Granite</a>"
```

Comment: I've tried that, but what it gives me is New Granite"> next to the image before I even click on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the word `new` to `_blank` and you're good to go.

Comment: I've tried that, but what it gives me is New Granite"> next to the image before I even click on the image.

Comment: That's because you're not properly opening and closing your href. Erase that line of code you've got and replace it with this... 

`<a href="images/fiandre/fiandre3.jpg" data-lightbox="fiandre" data-title=<a href="http://www.granitifiandre.com/porcelain-tile/technical-ceramic/granite-tiles/" target="_blank">New Granite</a>`

Comment: I don't have your image, so I can't display it, but you should get the general meaning.

Comment: I got it, i just have to tweak the lightbox JS.

Comment: Ok. Please add your tweak here. Others may come back and need this answer.