# Lightbox 2 removes target="_blank"'s behavior in data-title

Tags: html, tabs, lightbox2

I'm trying to use Lightbox's title function as a simple way to put PDF download links and website URLs so that people are able to see designs in full detail and actually visit interactive websites they've seen as images. I do it this way:

```
<a href="projects/img_full/my_project.png" data-lightbox="project1" data-title="<a href='http://example.com/' target='_blank'>Visit site</a>">
    <img src="projects/thumbs/my_project.png" alt="Project 1" />
</a>
```

The link outputs correctly under the Lightbox's image, and `target='_blank'` remains if I inspect it in my browser. However, **the link still opens in the same tab**.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, on my project page I have gallery of places, and in title I have an url to wiki site with description of current place, when I click on the link page opens in the same window, in firebug everything looks fine (with attribute target etc.)

I found something in Lightbox library that I think is responsible for running urls

```
  // Enable anchor clicks in the injected caption html.
  // Thanks Nate Wright for the fix. @https://github.com/NateWr
  if (typeof this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== 'undefined' && this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== "") {
    this.$lightbox.find('.lb-caption')
      .html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title)
      .fadeIn('fast')
      .find('a').on('click', function(event){
        location.href = $(this).attr('href');
      });
  }
```

but I'm not 100% sure that is this, could someone show where I can update code and depened opening links by the "target" attribute?

**EDIT:**

ok, found solution to this, need to replace code above with this and it works for me, found it on github
https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/pull/299/files

```
if (typeof this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== 'undefined' && this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== "") {
            this.$lightbox.find('.lb-caption')
                    .html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title)
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .find('a').on('click', function (event) {
                if ($(this).attr('target') !== undefined) {
                    window.open($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('target'));
                } else {
                    location.href = $(this).attr('href');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: An issue remains: opening a new tab with `window.open()` causes it to be blocked as a popup by the browser. I wonder if there's an alternate way to do it.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks so much!