# Open image link in new windows with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        if(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.prettyPhoto)) {
            $.prettyPhoto.open(
                "images/ad1.jpg", // Image to be opened
                "title",    // Title of the pop-up
                "desc."     // The description
            );
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.prettyPhoto.close();
            }, 8000); // autoclose after 8 seconds
        } else {
            console.log("PrettyPhoto is not defined."); // log this message
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I am trying to make an image (ad1.jpg) link url to be opened in a new tab window. How would I do this? I have tried many options to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to open it in a new tab or in a popup window?

Comment: WHy do you need it to open in a new tab rather than a window?

Answer (score 1):

This should work!

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://your_url_here.html">Link</a>
```

Hope this helps for more detail see the answer here [Open link in new tab or window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551779/open-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: This is just html rather than js