# Opening external links in the same new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to open external links in the **same new tab** in the same browser window ?

> *( i.e. first click in an external link triggers a new tab, but
>   subsequent clicks on the external links open up in that same tab
>   without creating additional tabs in the browser window )*

Example : See how **LegWorkStudio** doing it in their portfolio in between the following links

1. http://www.legworkstudio.com/interactive/laika-the-boxtrolls
2. http://www.legworkstudio.com/interactive/kentucky-fried-chicken
3. http://www.legworkstudio.com/interactive/newton-run-better
4. http://www.legworkstudio.com/interactive/coke-ahh-effect

Comment: Have you tried searching first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open link in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551779/open-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: I think the question might be to continuously open links in one single new tab. I.e., first link click triggers a new tab, but subsequent link clicks open up in that same tab without creating additional tabs?

Comment: @TedNyberg : Yes, I mean what you understood.

Comment: I took a look at the construction of the legworkstudio website and the don't load external links. All content you see when clicking on the links exists on the website as hidden div's. They only load a hidden div into another to display it. This can easily be done with a library like jQuery.

Comment: @Patel : Re-read the question please !!

Answer (score -1):

HTML :

```
<div id="target" />
<div id="source"><p>bla bla bla</p></div>
```

Content replacement via normal javascript :

```
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
```

Content replament via jQuery :

```
$("#target").html($("#source").html());
```

You can bind this code to a link by adding the onclick method to the link and wrapping it in a function (normal JS) or via the different methods of jQuery (on, click).

Example JS:

```
<a id="copytext" href="#" onclick='copyText();return false'>Copy text</a>
<script>
    function copyText() {
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

Example jQuery :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#copyref").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#target").html($("#source").html());
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm only asking for any code that demonstrating opening the external links on the same new tab, not how LegWorkStudio changing the display of the content from none to block.

Comment: checkout the documentation for the jQuery load method [https://api.jquery.com/load/]

Comment: I think you haven't understood the question . Please go through it again !!

Comment: As I allready stated before, all content exists on the page when it is loaded the first time. The only thing they do is show/hide the different content when you click on a link. The formatiing of the links is for having good SEO results. If you don't want to understand this, I can't help you any further.

Answer (score -2):

It seems they just change `window.location` variable `onclick` then operates some JS code to display the right section.

At load, they surely read the `window.location` last argument and display the right section.

You can make something like that :

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("sectionXXXButton");
myButton.onclick = function(){
    var a = window.location.split("/");
    a[a.length-1] = "XXX";
    window.location = a.join("/");
    // Some code to undisplay / display appropriate sections
}
```