# Need the below code to open a new tab instead of opening in current tab

Tags: html, onclick

I need the below code to open in new tab. The link is to a website which is specified with "Occupation Link 1"

```
{block:ifOccupation1}
    <a {block:ifOccupationlink1}onclick="window.location.href='{text:Occupation Link 1}'" style="cursor:pointer"{/block:ifOccupationlink1}>
        {text:Occupation 1}
    </a>
    {/block:ifOccupation1}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open link in new tab or window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551779/open-link-in-new-tab-or-window)

Answer (score 1):

Add `?target=_blank` to the end of the URL:

```
{block:ifOccupation1}
    <a {block:ifOccupationlink1}onclick="window.location.href='{text:Occupation Link 1}'" target='_blank' style="cursor:pointer"{/block:ifOccupationlink1}>
        {text:Occupation 1}
    </a>
{/block:ifOccupation1}
```

Comment: What is the URL that is produced at the end ?

Comment: Not `chathamink.com?target=_blank` ?

Comment: <div class="trigger-buttons">
          <a data-icon="&#xe022" original-icon="&#xe022" close-icon="&#xe023" class="menu-trigger"></a>
          <a data-icon="&#xe021" class="search-trigger"></a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="salvia-header">
          
          <div class="salvia-occupations">
        
        {block:ifOccupation1}
        <a {block:ifOccupationlink1}onclick="window.location.href='{text:Occupation Link 1}'" style="cursor:pointer"{/block:ifOccupationlink1}>
            {text:Occupation 1}
        </a>
        {/block:ifOccupation1}

Comment: Add the `target="_blank"` like I wrote

Comment: I did but its still not working. I'm not sure why. Even when I right click on the link it doesn't give me option to open in new tab. Acting like not a link but like text, but when you click it, it opens up correctly in the same tab

Comment: Is the web page external? Something I can look at ?

Comment: links are the three links at the top

Comment: It's without the _target: `<a onclick="window.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/chathamink/'" style="cursor:pointer">
            Like us on Facebook
        </a>
`

Comment: Are you **Sure** you uploaded the updated code to the website ??

Comment: I just changed the second link to add the target="_blank"

Answer (score 1):

to open a link in new tab all you need to do is add a target to it in your anchor tag, i.e, target="_blank". this '_blank' actually opens the required link in a new tab.

```
**<a {block:ifOccupationlink1}onclick="window.location.href='{text:Occupation Link 1}'" target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer"{/block:ifOccupationlink1}>
    {text:Occupation 1}
</a>**
```