# How do I add a link within this php?

Tags: php

Can someone please help me write this PHP so that the word `"here"` is a hyperlink to a new tab?

```
<p>
<?php printf( __( "Hi there. Your recent purchase for %s was successful. A confirmation PDF is attached and your order details are shown below for your reference. 
<br>
Have you heard about our upcoming CD release? Pre-order your copy now by clicking here", 'woocommerce' ), get_option( 'blogname' ) ); ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551842/362536

Answer (score -1):

```
<p>
<?php printf( __( "Hi there. Your recent purchase for %s was successful. A confirmation PDF is attached and your order details are shown below for your reference. 
<br>
Have you heard about our upcoming CD release? Pre-order your copy now by clicking <a href='path/to/file'>here</a>, 'woocommerce' ), get_option( 'blogname' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: You really need to escape data you're concatenating into HTML with `htmlspecialchars()` or equivalent.  Without this, you risk creating invalid HTML, or even potential security vulnerabilities.