# Canva.com, how can I have opend link in new tab

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am training to add links to my Canva project.

But I need links which one opens in new browser tab. Is anyone knows how  to do this?

[image]

Comment: Add `target='_blank'` to the `a` element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open link in new tab or window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551779/open-link-in-new-tab-or-window)

Comment: Anything that helps you in this? [https://www.canva.com/help/](https://www.canva.com/help/)

Comment: I try add target=“_blank” but there’s not working, because it need to be  url like https://web.com no html tag.

Answer (score 0):

To link to another website page, enter the link, and press Enter on your keyboard or click anywhere on the editor.

To link to another page within the design, select the page you want to link to from the Pages in this document section in the dropdown.

To link to one of your recent designs, select it from the Recent section in the dropdown. Make sure have the right permissions to the design you’re linking to so it loads properly to your audience.

Comment: Thanks,  Muhammad Nurfarhan. The problem I have is when I click on the link, I need it open on another tab. Like target=“_blank” do for HTML, but Canva clean links.

Comment: you're welcome, Marcin. you can try this adding rel="noopener noreferrer" is not mandatory, but it's a recommended security measure(for html). If that doesn't help, maybe the features of the Canva app don't support new tabs yet.